# No Screen Shows up in Mobile App, WebApp working fine

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to hybrid application developement, I am trying to make an application in angularJS, (Not IONIC). My App loads slow in browser but it works, however it doesnt work at all in mobile app..
I am serving it using grunt. But cant seem to figure out how to make it work in mobile..
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
 <head>
<title>Quiz App</title>
<!--Stylesheets-->
<!--Bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- injector:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/challenge.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/discussion.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/game.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/login.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/loginMail.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/profile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ranking.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/subjects.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/topics.css">
<!-- endinjector -->

<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<!--Scripts-->
<!-- JQuery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" ></script>
<!-- AngularJS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>-->
<!--Supersonic-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/supersonic/supersonic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/supersonic/supersonic.core.js"></script>-->
<!--Bootstrap-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<!-- Application -->
<!-- injector:js -->
<script src="scripts/App.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/config/Route.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/DiscussionService.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/ProfileService.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/RankingService.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/SubjectService.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/0-ExamBattleController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/Body/0-BodyController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/Body/BodyController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/ChallengeController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/DiscussionController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/GameController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/ProfileController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/RankingController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/SubjectController.js"></script>
<!-- endinjector -->

</head>
<body id="body">
<!--<p>App has loaded</p>-->
<div id="main" ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my app run and config

```
var BaseImagesUrl = 'images/';
var BaseTemplateUrl = 'templates/';

var app= angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.run(function($rootScope, $timeout, $location, $route){
    $rootScope.login = {};
    $rootScope.test = "Hello World";
    alert("app is running");
    console.log($route);
});
```

config goes here:

```
app.config(function($locationProvider,$routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: BaseTemplateUrl + 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .when('/loginMail', {
        templateUrl: BaseTemplateUrl + 'loginMail.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
     .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to start the angular app inside onDeviceReady.

```
onDeviceReady : function() {
   angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['examBattle']);
 });
```

}

Remove ng-app

Thanks,
Madan

Answer (score 0):

You should create your project using cordova CLI.

Like here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

I had so many problems with cordova months ago, so i moved my source to a new project created using CLI and everything is working.

The most important thing that you should considere when you move to CLI, is the informations about debug that CLI compiler give to you.

Comment: I have created it using cordova CLI

Comment: Try run using ripple (you can install ripple from chrome web store), if your app run in ripple and not running in mobile, so you have problems with cordova. if is a cordova problem, you can compile using cli and cli will show you the errors.